# Array key partly repeats, sort and divide by that

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [database_db_host] => localhost
    [database_db_user] => root
    [database_db_pass] => qwerty
    [database_db_db] => db
    [system_base] => http://www.mysite.com/
    [system_DEBUG_MODE] => 0
    [system_name] => mysite.com
    [system_VAT] => 20
    [appearance_copyright] => 2012 - 2013
    [appearance_DEFAULT_LANG] => 2
    [appearance_MULTI_CR_LEVELS] => 0
    [appearance_SEARCH_RESULTS_PER_PAGE] => 20
    [appearance_width] => 970
    [ads_ADS_ENABLED] => 1
    [ads_ADS_impression_cost] => 0.001
    [ads_ADS_min_auditory] => 100
)
```

I need to use those prefixes to overwrite the currently existing config files, my problem is I don't know how to efficiently do this. The only way I could think of is loop through the array to create new arrays according to the prefix and then loop all the arrays to get the values from them and loop again to save into files, which really doesn't look like an elegant way to do this. There must be a simpler way.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $prefixes = array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $prefixes[] = substr($key,0,strpos($key,'_'));
    }
    $prefixes = array_unique($prefixes);
    $ini_strings = array();
    foreach($prefixes as $prefix){
        $ini_strings[$prefix] = '';
        foreach($_POST as $setting => $value){
            if(strpos($setting,$prefix)===0){
                $quot = (is_numeric($value) ? '' : '"');
                $ini_strings[$prefix] .= str_replace($prefix.'_','',$setting).' = '.$quot.$value.$quot.PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($ini_strings as $ini => $settings){
        file_put_contents(phppages.'config/'.$ini.'.ini',$settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: What files are you writing these to? You're right, 3 loops sounds unnecessary, but please show what you've tried so far so we can see what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Shai I added the example script that is the ugliest script ever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. Two loops, but much cleaner code... if you really want you can do the whole thing in 1 loop but then you would have to write to each file more than once, which I don't really like doing.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $ini_strings = array();

    foreach($_POST as $key => $setting_value) {
        $parts = explode('_', $key);
        $prefix = array_shift($parts); // shift the first element off the array
        $setting_name = implode('_', $parts); // ...and put the rest back together

        /* at this point:
            $prefix is the prefix, e.g. ads
            $setting_name is the setting name e.g. ADS_min_auditory,
            $setting_value is the value e.g. 100
        */

        if (!array_key_exists($prefix, $ini_strings))
            $ini_strings[$prefix] = "";

        $quot = is_numeric($setting_value) ? '' : '"';
        $ini_strings[$prefix] .= $setting_name . ' = ' . $quot . $setting_value . $quot . PHP_EOL;
    }

    foreach($ini_strings as $ini => $settings) {
        file_put_contents(phppages . 'config/' . $ini . '.ini', $settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I actually realized was that I could set the form's input names to `name='$ini[$setting]'` instead of `name='$ini_$setting'` and then the code turned out to be 2 lines total. But please don't get mad because of my retardness, +rep! `:D`

Comment: @php_nub_qq If that option is available to you then definitely do that!